# How can I know whether my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone got rooted in the past (Android 9, One UI 1.0)?

Tags: rooting, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I know whether my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone got rooted in the past (Android 9, One UI 1.0)? (even though it might have been unrooted afterward)

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19821/is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-the-phone-has-been-rooted-or-not?rq=1

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you, hopefully there is some solution for Android 9.